# facing issue in reading line from a file in shell script

Tags: shell

This is a input file `file1.txt`:

```
premon D0000070 0x201 0x40
```

this is the script.
`script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
CommandFileName=$1
while read line # This will read a line from file1.txt
 do
   FileName="${line// /_}"
   echo $FileName

   cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 -b --agent=DCHUP --buffer-size=250000  #this will hold a buffer of size 2.5MB
   sleep 1

   cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 -m --agent=DCHUP # this will start monitoring 
   sleep 1

   cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 --up '$line' --agent=DCHUP  

   #this is the filtering condition // this should be replicate as  a command ->     cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 --up 'premon D0000070 0x201 0x40'  #here I suspect $line is taking \n char aswell, so the command is not giving the desire output. #am I correct $line is taking new line char ? if it is so then how to remove it. 

   cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 -s --agent=DCHUP #this will stop monitoring
   sleep 1

   cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 -g --agent=DCHUP --dir=/root/  
   # this will collect the logs in /root directory.  - here I am getting “Parsing error  , premon D0000070 0x201 0x40 is not valid error” # but when I  execute the same command with out using script , it is working fine

   #mv /root/*.BIN /root/$FileName
   done < $CommandFileName
```

hope my question is clear..

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question isnt very clear... but try removing the semi-colon at the end of the line

```
done < $CommandFileName;
```

I dont think it should be there. ^

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure what your question is, but I believe you are trying to take arguments to be passed to `cmviewer` from the input file.  Try:

```
while read args; do
...
cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 --up $args --agent=DCHUP
...
done < $CommandFileName
```

That is, just remove the quotes when passing the arguments to `cmviewer`.  Or perhaps you are wanting to pass all of the arguments as a single argument to `cmviewer`, in which case you must use double quotes:

```
cmviewer -- -u USUPPXY-0 --up "$args" --agent=DCHUP
```